# PHP Error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::update() What is going wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I don't understand why I get that error when I run following code

```
$user = $user->find_user_by_id_oop(2);
$user->password = "Pass";
$user->update();
```

here my find_user_by_id_oop method insite User class

```
public function find_user_by_id_oop($user_id) {
    global $database;
    $result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id= {$user_id} LIMIT 1");
    $found_user = $result->fetch_object();

    return $found_user;
}
```

here my update method inside User class also

```
public function update($userID, $username, $password, $first_name, $last_name, $email) {
    global $database;
    global $session;
    $name = trim($database->escape_string($username));
    $pass = trim($database->escape_string($password));
    $firstname = trim($database->escape_string($first_name));
    $lastname = trim($database->escape_string($last_name));
    $email_address = trim($database->connection->real_escape_string($email));

    $query = "UPDATE users SET username='$name' , password='$pass' , first_name='$firstname' , last_name='$lastname' , email='$email_address' where id=$userID";
    $res = $database->query($query);

    if ($res) {
        $session->message('Data Updated');
        return $res;
    } else {
        $session->message('Data Not Updated');
    }
}
```

also I have that variables on my class

```
public $username, $id, $first_name, $last_name, $password;
```

and i instantiate class outside of class brackets

```
$user = new User();
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Comment: You are overwriting your object with the result from SQL: `$user = $user->find_user_by_id_oop (2);`, use different variable names.

Comment: if you mean like that           $test =$user->find_user_by_id_oop (2);
            $test->password = "Pass";
            $user->update (); also not working

Comment: Could you define what is not working?

Comment: i cannot pass test pass on db table

Comment: That is because you are not passing any arguments to your function, right?

Comment: if i run update function like $user->update (2,"","","","",""); the function work fine

Comment: is not possible to update only pass using the way i used on top of my question?

Comment: This is how you have written the code. If you wanted to have a class User with properties populated from DB, you would need to create such logic.

Comment: you mean get all data from db and fill e.g form inputs and when update eg pass and submit form then all existing,updated data pass on my update function correct?

Comment: What? No. I meant that instead of returning the DB object in `find_user_by_id_oop`, use it to populate the properties of User object

Answer (score 0):

My issue is fixed by pass classname on fetch_object(User::class);

Fixed Function Below

```
   public static function find_user_by_id_oop($user_id)
{
    global $database;
    $result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id= {$user_id} LIMIT 1");
    return $result->fetch_object(User::class);

}
```

i found related info here : [mysqli_result::fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

```
class_name
```

The name of the class to instantiate, set the properties of and return. If not specified, a stdClass object is returned.